# HashMap, где ключ - String, а значение - ArrayList

Tags: java

Есть `Map`, в котором хочу в качестве ключа использовать `String`, а в качестве `value` - `ArrayList`. Но предполагаю, что такой подход многим опытным программистам покажется ужасным. Я прав?

Comment: Я думаю, что красивый подход - это когда понятный код. Если так удобнее, то лучше использовать так.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ничего ужасного. Особенно при отсутствии реализации `multimap` в `Collection Framework`.

Но можно воспользоваться сторонними реализациями `multimap`. Например, `Apache Commons Collection` или `Google Collections`.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Кстати, обратите внимание, что Google Collections ныне называется Guava.